# How to count record with two different tables in sql?

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables called `clientorder` and `orderitemstatus`.

**orderitem**

```
+-----+------------+-------------+
| clid| orderitem  | orderstatus |
+-----+------------+-------------+
| 1   | books      |   6         |
| 2   | books1     |   7         |
| 1   | books2     |   8         |
| 4   | books3     |   6         |
| 1   | books4     |   8         |
| 6   | books5     |   7         |
| 2   | books6     |   6         |
+-----+------------+-------------+
```

**orderitemstatus**

```
+----+---------------+
| id | iddescription |
+----+---------------+
| 6  | job held      |
| 7  | pre-press     |
| 8  | onqueue       |
| 9  | sent          |
+----+---------------+
```

now I want to count clients `orderstatus` with respective client id the result should be

**Expected Output**

```
+------+---------+-----------+---------+------+
| clid | jobheld | pre-press | onqueue | sent |
+------+---------+-----------+---------+------+
| 1    | 2       | 1         | 0       | 2    | 
| 2    | 2       | 1         | 0       | 2    |
| 3    | 4       | 1         | 0       | 2    |
| 6    | 1       | 1         | 0       | 2    |
+------+---------+-----------+---------+------+
```

and I tried this one but i am getting only one job status

**Query**

```
select count(cloi_current_status) as jobheld 
from dbo.CLOI_ClientOrderItems 
where cloi_current_status=9 and cl_id='1'
```

Comment: How did u get `jobheld=2` for `clid=1`?

Comment: just i shown you the example that is dummy record

Comment: Please provide more information about the expected result

Comment: Your expected result doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

```
SELECT i.clid,
       SUM(CASE WHEN s.iddescription = 'jobheld' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as jobheld,
       SUM(CASE WHEN s.iddescription = 'prep-press' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as pre_press,
       SUM(CASE WHEN s.iddescription = 'onqueue' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as onqueue,
       SUM(CASE WHEN s.iddescription = 'sent' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as sent,
       COUNT(*) AS total,
       SUM(CASE WHEN s.iddescription IN ('jobheld', 'pre-press', 'onqueue') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as whatever
  FROM orderitem i
  JOIN orderstatus s
    ON i.orderstatus = s.id
 GROUP
   BY i.clid
```

Comment: k and one more i want to add one more column total in that total display jobheld+pre-pres+onqueue+sent=total how to add

Comment: The total is row count per `clid`, so a new new column `COUNT(*) AS total`. See updated answer.

Comment: if i want only 3 column  jobheld+pre-pres+onqueue=total..?

Comment: How about to find out by yourself, take a look at the other `CASE` expressions

Comment: SUM(CASE WHEN s.iddescription IN ('jobheld', 'pre-press', 'onqueue') THEN 1 ELSE 0) as whatever in this case its giving

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the [`PIVOT` operator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
SELECT clid, [6] AS jobheld, [7] AS [pre-press], [8] AS onqueue, [9] AS [sent]
FROM clientorder
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(orderitem)
    FOR orderstatus IN ([6], [7], [8], [9])
) AS pvt
```

Here's the result I get with your data:

```
+------+---------+-----------+---------+------+
| clid | jobheld | pre-press | onqueue | sent |
+------+---------+-----------+---------+------+
| 1    | 1       | 0         | 2       | 0    |
| 2    | 1       | 1         | 0       | 0    |
| 4    | 1       | 0         | 0       | 0    |
| 6    | 0       | 1         | 0       | 0    |
+------+---------+-----------+---------+------+
```

Comment: @user3796682 getting what? I edited the answer and added the result I get when running the query.